# How to show only base url in addressbar using Codeigniter

Tags: php, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2

the main url looks like this : http://www.test.com/test/exm/123/ . now we want to show only baseurl(http://www.test.com) to the clients. the site created using codeigniter frame work. so my question is how can i hide methods and parameters from the URL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get it from base_url();

Comment: You will be needing a serious ht access code for that. as you might be having n no. of controller and n no of methods and all needs to hidden from the url.. I would suggest not to do something like this. rather than that. just hide index.php and let them see the controllers and method name. it will make your site SEO friendly also

Comment: I included a .htaccess file to my root file. it removes index,php from the url.